# Maximum and minimum penalty in lasso regression family

Tags: lambda, regression, linear-regression, lasso-regression

I am trying to adjust penalty, lambda, in group lasso regression, but I have no idea about it.
I am wondering is there any theory or rule about maximum and minimum value of lambda based on x, input, and y, response?
I need an automatic procedure to determine the minimum and maximum value of penalty b/c I have more than `10 thousands of response variables` which regress on `more than 500 independent variables`.
I appreciate if anyone can help me, I am new in regression field.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a question that would be better suited to http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thank you. I was not familiar with [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com), I have just signed up!